# How to add mecab package in aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, mecab

- My goal is :

  create custom api on AWS-lambda which uses mecab to analyze the data.
- Problem is:

  when i run test on aws-lambda it throws this kind of error.

  ```
  Execution result: failed(logs)
  {
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_MeCab' from 'MeCab' (/var/task/MeCab/__init__.py)",
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to use this library :

1. Either create layer and upload library package folder there Then mapped this layer to lambda service
2. Upload library package folder inside lambda package.

How to find library package folder : https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Layer documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: i have tried 2nd option, and reason why i mention MeCab is because this package requires some specific path configuration i think.

Comment: btw thanks for your answer. but i have no idea which mecab file should be in path. can you explain more clearly please.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. but i have also tried first option, but the response is still the same.


[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_MeCab' from 'MeCab' (/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MeCab/__init__.py)

Comment: you have to copy folder inside `site-packages` folder.

Comment: it's inside exactly that folder. but somehow it doesn't recognize it. but the other packages for example bs4, mojimoji etc are same directory as Mecab and they working correctly.